# Write a PLIST file in Groovy

Tags: java, groovy, plist

I have a Groovy application for Windows and am trying to convert a Hash object to an Apple plist file. What is the best way to go about this? Seems like this is something that must already be solved in Java but I can't seem to find any examples.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [commons-configuration](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/), it is designed (to a certain extend) to allow you to write data to any configuration format.